# $x^3-3ax+b$ has $3$ real roots and $a$ and $b$ are real. The roots are $m < n < p$.

Tags: polynomials

$x^3-3ax+b$ has $3$ real roots and $a$ and $b$ are real. The roots are $m < n < p$.
Then show that:
$m < - \sqrt {|a|} < n < \sqrt {|a|} < p$. where $a>0$

By Vieta:

$m+n+p=0$, $mn+np+pm=-3a$ and $mnp=b$ But then how to get this?

Answer (score 3):

HINT :

Let $f(x)=x^3-3ax+b$.

Then, $f'(x)=3x^2-3a=3(x^2-a)$ from which it follows that $a\gt 0$.

Now consider the graph of $y=f(x)$.

Comment: I would prefer a rigourous solution without graphs